# Windows 2003 (actually XP x64) can't read SSL signature if it's SHA-2 (SHA 256/384/512)

Tags: windows-xp, ssl, perl, windows-server-2003, sha-2

I have a Windows XP Professional x64 virtual machine to run some HLDS processes. I chose the x64 edition as I already have a license for it, and as it uses the Windows Server 2003 kernel it'll be more reliable (and up longer) than Windows XP Professional x86.

The HLDS processes have their game contents updated from our subversion repository, which requires HTTPS transport. We have our own CA for this, and all our certificates use SHA-2 (SHA512) signatures with RSA 4096-bit keys. Sub-version works fine with this right away. I also use a Perl script to periodically check the subversion repository for a new revision every 3 minutes, which also downloads updates if available, and stops/starts the HLDS processes if the update includes server binaries.

The issue is no applications would claim the signature of our SSL certificates are valid. Chrome, IE8, and Perl would all be affected. I found hotfixes **KB938397**, **KB968730**, and **KB2641690** which apparently fix this, but they have not fully done so. Chrome now works fine with our certificates, but IE8 and Perl are not. Pretty odd that subversion (SlikSVN and TortoiseSVN) are not affected by this.

Other things I've tried is installing our root CA into the local computer's trusted root certificate authorities store, ensuring all Perl modules are updated, and installing OpenSSL.

I'm not too bothered if IE8 never works with these certificates, but I really need Perl to work.

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: You have to tell us what "HLDS" stands for.  Have you verified your certificate works on another operating system.  In other words have you confirmed this is only a `Windows XP x64` problem?

Comment: HLDS is Half-Life dedicated server (standalone game server process). Didn't mention it as it wasn't relative to the issue, and just an outline of that the VM's purpose is for. All the certificates work fine on other operating systems, including Windows XP x86.

Comment: Have you verified the modification dates on the files updated by the hotfixes in question?

Comment: Crypt32.dll (in System32 and SysWOW64) are both later versions than those provided by the hotfixes. Would post details, but no line breaks allowed in comments :( Wcrypt32.dll not found anywhere in %SystemRoot%. Perhaps I need an older version of this library to resolve this?